# Why is selenium not working even after I've installed it in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have both python 3.7 and 3.8. I've tried installing and uninstalling selenium multiples times, using a different command line in the terminal each time. Some things I've tried are

`pip install selenium`
`sudo pip install selenium`
`sudo pip3 install selenium`
`sudo -H pip3 install -U selenium`

I have even downloaded selenium-3.141.0.tar.gz from the [pypi website](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/#files), and run the set up file.

I consistently get the following message:

`Requirement already satisfied: selenium in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.141.0) Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from selenium) (1.25.9)`

However, when I try `from selenium import webdriver` in python, I get the following error message:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>from selenium import webdriver ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'`

Why is python telling me that it is not installed but my terminal is telling me that it is already installed?

Comment: Try running the Anaconda shell first: `conda.bat activate` then press Ctrl-D to exit the python console. Then run your script.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you should check: **Virtual Environment Compatibilities**
If you have a virtual environment for your project, you may have an issue where the package is not part of the dependencies defined in the venv if the venv was made before the selenium installation OR the project does not use the Python venv version. So you can rectify by

1. Go to your bash terminal and activate the virtual environment

   ```
   $source venv\Scripts\activate #or can be
   $source venv\bin\activate
   ```
2. Install selenium in the virtual environment with any of those commands depending on your version of Python.
3. Also make sure that in your editor, the settings are such that the venv is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `python3 -m pip install selenium` in the terminal

Comment: I just tried this and I still get the same error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Comment: I am not too sure but I think this video can be of potential help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HcXCEW7MSzo

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Instructions for Windows users](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html) in the Selenium installation instructions.
It perfectly works, you just need to find your python path and it is generally something like this: `C:\Users\"yourname"\AppData\Local\Programs\Python`